# Where to store videos for video streaming android app?

Tags: android, flutter, storage, hosting

I am developing an android app for children to learn which is a video streaming service. I need to store some GB size of videos for the app. I am wondering if app users fetch the same video at the same time, which service and storing option can help this issue?
Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at **cloud firestore's** [storage service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) which is 5GB of storage for free and **$0.026/GB** per month after exceeding 5GB. Firestore is pretty easy to set up with flutter.

I recommend you look through what cloud firestore and see if it is what you are looking for along with calculating the [price](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) of it.

Comment: I thought of this. But on the other hand, I am wondering that will it solve concurrency streaming for the video?